# Input doesnt appear on database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I've been trying to add an input from my python program into the table i made on sqlite but for some reason it doesnt pop up when looking through the table.

def create():

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, unique(userid, name))")
```

def save_results():

```
print('Please enter your first and last name...')

name = input('Enter: ').upper()

c.execute('INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES(?)', [name])
```

## the input would be john smith

The output i would be expecting is for john smith to appear in the table along with an auto-incremented userID.

Comment: Don't define a composite unique constraint for an auto-number id AND another column.  Since the id's should already be unique, this is ineffective and would allow duplicate names in the table.  They should individually be declared unique.

Comment: Not sure of this, but I know that tuples are used to pass parameters values.  Python lists might not work... although I would expect an exception to be thrown if it doesn't work.  In other words, try changing `[name]` to a single-component tuple like `(name,)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missing commit. Review the [doc here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html).  The last comment in the first code snippet before `conn.close()` says

> Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.

```
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
conn.close()
```

Comment: Ive added the conn.commit() and the conn.close() but the input still isnt being saved into the data base